# python code gives me error or "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

Tags: python, web-scraping

How to fix a problem with the function to obtain an actual result?

python

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/berlin-kai-wegner-mit-einfacher-mehrheit-zum-regierenden-buergermeister-gewaehlt-a-5a9f9458-0987-4158-b898-c06791016d28"

page = requests.get(url).content
html = requests.get(url)
print(html.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find("h1").find(class_="font-normal whitespace-nowrap inline-block text-black dark:text-shade-lightest text-s pl-4 pr-16 pb-px").text

# Rest of the code or description of the problem
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are "kind of" correct, but they don't explain **why** your code is failing.

Using `find(...).find(...)` you are *not* searching within the full result of the first search.  The documentation says that `find()` and `find_all()` search within the **descendants** of the current tag.

In your case, if you check the result of your first `find` action, you will note that it is the first location (as promised) of the `h1` level item (which coincidentally is the only one on the page) and it happens to be the one you are looking for **not** any of the descendants.  It has no `Tag` descendants, just the `NavigableString` (which I don't really understand why, but bottom line: it isn't a `Tag` so it won't be searched.)  So, either combine the search terms or just look for `h1` because it happens to be a singleton in your case.

##### Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/berlin-kai-wegner-mit-einfacher-mehrheit-zum-regierenden-buergermeister-gewaehlt-a-5a9f9458-0987-4158-b898-c06791016d28"

page = requests.get(url).content
html = requests.get(url)
# print(html.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

def full_class_match(cls):
    if cls:
        # print(f'matching: {cls}')
        return cls == "font-normal whitespace-nowrap inline-block text-black dark:text-shade-lightest text-s pl-4 pr-16 pb-px"
    return False

t1 = soup.find('h1')  # of course this will only find the first (one result)

t2 = soup.find('h1', class_='font-normal')  # see the dox on class searching

t3 = soup.find('h1', class_=full_class_match)

assert t1 == t2 == t3

# inspecting result:
print(f'tag text: {t2.string}')
print(f'tag attrs: {t2.attrs}')
print('scanning descendants:')
for idx, descendant in enumerate(t2.descendants, 1):
    print(f'    descenant #{idx} is a : {type(descendant)}')
    print('    ', descendant.string)
```

##### Output:

```
tag text: 
Berlin: Kai Wegner mit absoluter Mehrheit zum Regierenden Bürgermeister gewählt

tag attrs: {'class': ['font-normal', 'whitespace-nowrap', 'inline-block', 'text-black', 'dark:text-shade-lightest', 'text-s', 'pl-4', 'pr-16', 'pb-px']}
scanning descendants:
    descenant #1 is a : <class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>
     
Berlin: Kai Wegner mit absoluter Mehrheit zum Regierenden Bürgermeister gewählt
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code is, that the `soup.find()` method did not find a matching element for the specified classes and it is returning `None`. When the code attempted to access the text attribute on this None object, it resulted in the error

> "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

You can use the if to check if it is None or not

Like This

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/berlin-kai-wegner-mit-einfacher-mehrheit-zum-regierenden-buergermeister-gewaehlt-a-5a9f9458-0987-4158-b898-c06791016d28"

page = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

title_element = soup.find("h1").find(class_="font-normal whitespace-nowrap inline-block text-black dark:text-shade-lightest text-s pl-4 pr-16 pb-px")
if title_element is not None:
    title = title_element.text
    print(title)
else:
    print("Title element not found.")
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a mistake in the last line

```
title = soup.find("h1").find(class_="font-normal whitespace-nowrap inline-block text-black dark:text-shade-lightest text-s pl-4 pr-16 pb-px").text
```

You're finding a tag, then finding its class, which isn't the syntax of BeautifulSoup, correct syntax is

```
variable = soup.find(tag, class_='some class')
```

So, your correct code should be

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/berlin-kai-wegner-mit-einfacher-mehrheit-zum-regierenden-buergermeister-gewaehlt-a-5a9f9458-0987-4158-b898-c06791016d28"

page = requests.get(url).content
html = requests.get(url)
print(html.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
title = soup.find("h1", class_="font-normal whitespace-nowrap inline-block text-black dark:text-shade-lightest text-s pl-4 pr-16 pb-px").text
```